# All my records are deleted, how to cancel it?

Tags: algolia

All my record on one indices was been deleted i don't know why. Is there a way to retreive them?

How can I cancel it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to debug that is to look at your Algolia logs, you can even inspect them at the index level.

It's unfortunately not cancelable (kind of similar to a database where you're not able to "cancel" DELETE options); you'll need to repush your data to Algolia.